# Select row values that are in repeated rows that have a colum with at least 3 different values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this

```
Ma Mi
-----
A  b
A  c
A  c
A  d
B  b
B  a
B  a
B  a
B  a
C  a
C  b
```

I want to make a select that outputs only the "Ma" values that have at least 3 distinct "Mi" values, i've tryed group by and distinct unsuccesfully since i want to group first "Mi" and then count "Ma" with distinct "Mi".

So the intermediate step would be :

```
Ma Mi
-----
A  b
A  c
A  d
B  b
B  a
C  a
C  b
```

So then i can count the rows per each Ma

In this case, the result would be

```
Ma num
------
A   3
B   2
C   2
```

And I could select only A because is the unique equal or higher to 3.

RESULT:

```
Ma num
------
A   3
```

Thank you in advanced !

L.

Comment: What is distinct in Mi column?

Comment: there are repeated a's and c's but i want them to group acording to Ma so it gets like the new edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check the results of a GROUP BY operation, you must use HAVING:

```
SELECT Ma,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Mi) AS Num
FROM ATableLikeThis
GROUP BY Ma
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Mi) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find query as per your requirement:

```
Select Distinct MyTable.Ma, 
       (Select Count(Distinct MyTableAlias.Mi) From MyTable As MyTableAlias Where MyTableAlias.Ma = MyTable.Ma) As Num from MyTable WHere (Select Count(Distinct MyTableAlias.Mi) From MyTable As MyTableAlias Where MyTableAlias.Ma = MyTable.Ma) >= 3
```